# LINQ to get individual values of a data table

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, t-sql, .net-3.5

I have the following DataTable:

Table1:

```
Location    FY_Quarter  .NET    java     SAP    Total
Bangalore    Q3          40      60      40     140
Bangalore    Q4          50      80      30     160
Bangalore    Q1          70      50      40     160
Bangalore    Q2          30      90      50     170
Chennai      Q3          80      40      60     180
Chennai      Q4          45      50      35     130
Chennai      Q1          60      75      65     200
Chennai      Q2          55      35      90     180
```

How to get/fetch each individual value from the above datatable very simplest way using LINQ. Here `Location`, `FY_Quarter` column data are dynamically generated.
I don't want to loop through entire datatable.

How can i acheive **using LINQ in ASP.NET using C#.NET;.NET3.5 F/w**

Comment: What do you want the resulting dataset to look like?

Comment: @DownVoter: Care to comment.Resultant Dataset should looks like as same as i given in the table above. How to get the above resultant with a simple LINQ query expression.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is some represented by an object you can to this:

```
var result = from items in Table1
             select new { Location = items.Location, FY_Quarter = items.FY_quarter};
```

Comment: I need the value as 40 for the first row in the  above table. How to get??

Comment: How can i pick third datarow from the above table

Comment: It seems you want us to do your work for you. For filtering on linq you can use a where clause and then add all the filters  you want.